# Update statement using sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I have copied 3 columns data to a file-

```
       echo "copy admin.product (old_column, id, date) to 'updateStatement.cql';" > copyInputs.cql
```

I got o/p file something like this-
       ,4.IM-H-506X,2016-01-01 11:07:27-0500
       ['LOWERCASETEST7'],JASONTEST7,2015-04-19 00:00:00-0400
       "['EPROSP_IWS', '648099_EPROSP_IWS']",4.NDR-IWS-EPRO,2015-04-16 08:04:21-0400

since my newly added column data having data type of map So i have changed my 1st column with {'my_old_column':''} format using sed command-

```
      sed "s/\(\"*\[[^]]*\]\"*\)\(.*\)/{\1:\"\"}\2/" tempFile
```

I got the desired o/p in tempfile-

```
        ,4.SMA-LCC-TERM,2015-02-19 00:00:00-0500
        {"['IWSSTMT', 'IWSSTMTI', 'EDEL_STMT_IWS']":""},4.IWS-ESTMT-NDR,2015-04-16 08:04
        {['RTS2']:""},MS2,2015-05-14 12:20:00-0400
```

Now again i ran sed command  to prepare update statement using but o/p is not comming properly. I guess expression is not correct in sed.

```
    sed "s/' *, *'/' '/g;s/\({^,}*\),\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/update table set my_new_column = \1 where id = \2 and date = \3/;s/' '/','/g" tempFile > updatestmt.cql
```

expected o/p-

```
      update table set my_new_column = {"['IWSSTMT', 'IWSSTMTI', 'EDEL_STMT_IWS']":""} where id = 4.IWS-ESTMT-NDR and date = 2015-04-16 08:04
```

Comment: Could you explain in words what your update is trying to do, instead of having us trying to figure it out based on the expected output? And what didn't work exactly? "Didn't work" is a very unspecific description.

Comment: @Cyrus Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers would be more appropriate.